# How can I programmatically add a cert to installed browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, certificate

I have a cert generated through a custom protocol and I would like to add it to a browsers store (and and all browsers: ie, firefox, chrome, safari) so that it can use it to authenticate. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I hope this is NOT possible. It would be a security risk.

Comment: a client cert, not server. (i.e. the cert authenticates the machine it is on to the server it is trying to connect to)

Comment: Programmatically?I think you should look at `CryptoAPI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox stores certificates in the three `.db` files in the [user profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile). So you would need to go through all existing profiles and change them. That can be done using [NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/), particularly the [`certutil` command line tool](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html) and for PKCS #12 files also [`pk12util`](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/pk12util.html). Depending on your goals you could of course also integrate NSS into your application and call its functions without using any command line tools. Note that IMHO adding a client certificate requires entering the master password for the database if one is set.